# wpdb->insert in ANY table always in third column inserts 0 instead of submitted string. Same string is inserted OK if submitted to another column

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, string

I have three tables defined where *always*

- column 3 is "query", varchar(255) null
- column 4 is "tag", varchar(255) null
- both columns are the same charset

I submit string $s to column 3 via `$wpdb->insert` which should do sanitization (but adding extra sanitization to col 3 and col 4 or not adding it does not change anything at all)

```
function abc($a=null,$tag=null) {
  global $wpdb;
  $data = array(
    'timestamp'     => time(),
    'query'         => sanitize_text_field($a),
    'tag'           => sanitize_text_field($tag)
  );
  $format = array('%s','%d');
  $wpdb->insert(SS_STATS,$data,$format);
  return $wpdb->insert_id;
}
```

in the template I tried:

```
abc($s,$s);
abc("$s","$s");
abc("plz save this","$s");
abc("plz save this","plz save this: $s");
```

In each and every case, column 3 in the db recods `0`. In each and every case, column 4 records the correct value just as it is submitted.

Why?

I tried:

- changing the name of the column (maybe query is protected)
- adding extra sanitization
- not adding any sanitization
- changing data type to text
- changing data type to blob

For every attempt I drop the db and let it recreate.

No change in any case.

How can I save the string in column 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the format:

```
$format = array('%s','%d');
  $wpdb->insert(SS_STATS,$data,$format);
```

Removing the formatting solved the issue.

`$wpdb->insert(SS_STATS,$data);`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the format was set incorrectly, assuming the three variable are strings, it should be set so:

```
$format = array( '%s', '%s', '%s' );
```